# Is there any String.startsWith(String) for angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have similar to following working code

```
<section class="row-fluid result" ng-repeat="result in getResults()">
<p>{{result.name}}</p>
<p>{{result.link}}</p>
</section>
```

the `result` have another property called resultId
where `result.resultId` will return one of following source prefixes: One, Two,Three.

For example these are typical resultId: `One3244243, One23036043, Two3890234, Three23114232`

Whereas prefixes means:

```
One=Source ABC
Two=Source XYZ
Three=Source WXY
```

So, now I want to also display the sources of the each result based on result's id 
prefixes:

```
<section class="row-fluid result" ng-repeat="result in getResults()">
<p>{{result.name}}</p>
<p>{{result.link}}</p>
<p><!-- display 'Source ABC' if result.resultId starts with One --> </p>
<p><!-- display 'Source XYZ' if result.resultId starts with Two--> </p>
<p><!-- display 'Source WXY' if result.resultId starts with Three --> </p>

</section>
```

Comment: Do `ng-show="result.resultId.indexOf('One') == 0"`, etc.

Comment: @ultraviol3tlux it worked, please post it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Do `ng-show="result.resultId.indexOf('One') == 0"`, etc.